# Select data between datetime range

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, range, between

I have a table called `lap` and it contains data like this :

```
code | name | details | time_stamp
===================================
1a   | A-wan| Goods   | 01-02-2019 11:08:10
3a   | D-wan| Goods   | 05-02-2019 01:00:40
2a   | B-gud| Foods   | 02-03-2019 05:31:05
1a   | A-cro| Bills   | 02-03-2019 15:30:15
1a   | A-set| Bills   | 03-03-2019 17:24:35
1a   | C-won| Goods   | 03-03-2019 10:21:55
1a   | C-gud| Foods   | 04-03-2019 01:30:06
```

I used `dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss` format

and my query
`SELECT * FROM lap WHERE time_stamp >= '02-03-2019 00:00:00' AND time_stamp <= '03-03-2019 23:59:59'`

the result is

```
code | name | details | time_stamp
===================================
3a   | D-wan| Goods   | 05-02-2019 01:00:40
2a   | B-gud| Foods   | 02-03-2019 05:31:05
1a   | A-cro| Bills   | 02-03-2019 15:30:15
1a   | A-set| Bills   | 03-03-2019 17:24:35
1a   | C-won| Goods   | 03-03-2019 10:21:55
```

it includes the data of
 `3a   | D-wan| Goods   | 05-02-2019 01:00:40`
i think it's may be because of `05` is bigger than `02` although it's different month.
Anyone can help this?

when i change the query on the same date it works well
`SELECT * FROM lap WHERE time_stamp >= '02-03-2019 00:00:00' AND time_stamp < '02-03-2019 23:59:59'`

```
code | name | details | time_stamp
===================================
2a   | B-gud| Foods   | 02-03-2019 05:31:05
1a   | A-cro| Bills   | 02-03-2019 15:30:15
```

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM lap WHERE time_stamp
BETWEEN '02-03-2019 00:00:00' AND '03-03-2019 23:59:59'`?

Comment: @nDy what is the data type of `time_stamp` in your database table?

Comment: 05 is the day not the month.

Comment: Store dates/times using a proper date/time data type

Comment: Yes, i have tried `SELECT * FROM lap WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '02-03-2019 00:00:00' AND '03-03-2019 23:59:59'`. It's doesn't worked

Comment: @nik select 2 between 3 and 1

Comment: i store the dates using format `$stamp=date("d-m-Y H:i:s T", time());`

Comment: What is the column type in the database?

Comment: @Nik it's varchar

Comment: Then you are comparing not the time but strings. You should use proper column type. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `date` function then it will work,

```
SELECT * FROM lap WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '02-03-2019' AND '03-03-2019';
```

or you can change the format to `yyyy-mm-dd` into your backend and check

```
SELECT * FROM lap WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2019-03-02' AND '2019-03-03';
```

Comment: if i use this function, not all data will showed.
it must include the time

Comment: i have used the same query and getting the result.
and without time if you mention the date it will automatically get the entire data from start time 1 to 24 hrs.you can also change the format to yyyy-mm-dd and check

Comment: i'm affraid i must change all my data if i must change teh date format

Comment: In this case you can user sql dateformat function, for example
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your column name, "%d %m %Y")  FROM your_table_name;

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 SELECT * FROM lap WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('02-03-2019 00:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %h:%m:%s') AND DATE_FORMAT('03-03-2019 23:59:59', '%d-%m-%Y %h:%m:%s');
```

for mysql date time format see link bellow
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

If you pass the date in another format its better you change the format.

Comment: i try this code, but unfortunedly it show zero result.